# UIViews moving after segue and return

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, ios8

I have an app in which I am creating a two views stacked on top of each other:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height -200)];
[self.view addSubview:headerView];
[self.view addSubview:bottomView];

[headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[bottomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

I also use a sidemenu which uses:

```
[self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"welcomeScreen"]]
                                                     animated:YES];
[self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
```

The initial load is fine and both top and bottom views appear as expected, however, when I navigate away using the side menu and then navigate back to home using the sidemenu, both views appear to move up the page (behind the navigation bar).

I have tried everything I can think from programmatic constraints to checking that the Navigation bar is present and moving the code from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear but I always get the same result. Any ideas as to what is happening and why? And any suggestions on a fix would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Update to this: Its definitely something to do with the navigation bar not being observed when I return to the view. As I can see on initial load that this is solid white, however on subsequent loads it's translucent with the content visible behind. If I add the UINavigationBarDelegate and give this a property in the .h can this be added to my constraints list?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) { 
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

Has fixed the issue!